# "Skip over" section of code over a period of time in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a bit of code in VB.Net which will send a trigger to turn on an IP camera when a sensor changes it's state (i.e 0 to 1 or 1 to 0).

I have done this, however I would like that when the sensor is triggered, the IP camera will trigger then wait 30 seconds before triggering again while the sensor is still triggering normally. My goal is to prevent rapid triggering of the IP Camera.

All of this is done in a background worker. After doing some research, I have found that I could stop the background worker for 30 seconds, but this is not really what I want, as the sensor would stop also. I don't really want to put a time delay in there either, for the same reason.

I was wondering if I could "skip over" a section of code for a period of time, within a background worker? For Example:

```
    If SensorHasChangedStatus() = True Then

      'execute this bit of code once then skip over it for 30 seconds
      triggerCamera()
      'end of code to skip over

      'do other stuff

   End If
```

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into timers?

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can create a timer with an interval and write your own event handler to trigger each time that interval is reached.

So you could trigger your camera, setup a condition to skip any further calls and then start a timer to reverse the condition after 30s allowing the camera to be triggered again.

Here's a basic example that triggers every 3s and just writes to console.

```
Sub Main()

    'Create a timer with interval of 3s
    Dim timer As New Timer(3000)

    'Set handler to trigger each interval
    AddHandler timer.Elapsed, New ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf elapseHandler)

    'Start timer
    timer.Enabled = True

    'Demo loop
    While timer.Enabled
    End While

End Sub

'Handler
Public Sub elapseHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("3s Passed")
    'Do stuff here every interval
End Sub
```